# equipollent couple of points to define vectors

Tags: geometry, proof-verification, vector-spaces, proof-writing, vectors

I have found this unusual yet very neat definition of a vector from an old math lesson of mine, it is quite clever, so that I decided to prove some theorems and share it here, so that they be verified !

**Definition 1 :** we call **bipoint** any couple of point of a plane $P$. Let $A$ be a point of $P$, the bipoint $(A,A)$ is called a **null bipoint**

**Definition 2 :** We say that two bipoints, say $(A,B) \& (C,D)$ are **equipollents** iff both segments [A;D] and [C;B] share the same midpoint. We denote this $(A,B) \sim (C,D)$

It is clear that for all points A & B, $(A,B) \sim (A,B)$

**Lemma 1 :** $\sim$ is an equivalence relation*,  moreover we have $(A,A) \sim (B,B)$

Please note : ABBA is considered as a flat parallellogram, as $(AB)\parallel(AB)$
Let us now define collinearity, length, and directions of bipoints.

**Definition 3&4 :** We call length of a bipoint the length of the segments that joins the two points. two non-null bipoints say $(A,B) \& (C,D)$ are called collinear if $(AB)\parallel(CD)$.

**Definition 5 :** two collinear bipoints $(A,B) \& (C,D)$ with A,B,C,D  not being aligned, are said to have the **same direction** if $ABDC$ is a trapezoid.

Let A,B,C,D be aligned points on a line E, let P be a point that doesn't lie on E, and let $\delta$ be the line parallel to E through P. Let $\epsilon_1$ be the line perpendicular to E through A and $\epsilon_2$ the line perpendicular to E through B, they cross line $\delta$ at point $A_2 \& B_2$, respectively. Then it 
is clear that $(A;B)$ has the same direction as $(A_2;B_2)$ (this forms a rectangle, which is a parallellogram and a trapezoid).

We say that (A,B) has the same direction as (C,D) iff ($A_2$,$B_2$) has the same direction as $(C,D)$

**Fundamental theorem:** Two non-null bipoints are equipollents iff they are collinear & have both the same length and direction.

**Proof :**

$(\Rightarrow)$ : ABDC is a trapezoid as both bipoints have the same direction. Moreover they both have the same length AB=CD, so ABDC is a parallellogram. So $(A,B)\sim(C,D)$

$(\Leftarrow)$ : $(A,B) \sim (C,D) $ so ABDC is a parallellogram, so it is a trapezoid so same direction is proven, moreover AB=CD so they have the same length.

**Definition 6 :** The set of all bipoints equipolents to $(A;B)$ (which is not empty as it contains $(A,B)$ ), is denoted by $\overrightarrow{AB}$. the vector $\overrightarrow{AA}$ is noted by $\vec{0}$. Vectors may also be denoted by a letter, in which case a rightarrow sits atop of it .

(*) I did not know what equivalence relation was back when I was taught this, so,$ \overrightarrow{AB}$ is the equivalence class of $(A,B)$ , right ?

So that finally :

**Fundamental theorem, reloaded** : Two vectors are equal iff they have the same direction and length.

which leads to

**Theorem 3 :** let $\vec u$ be a vector and A a point of P, then there exist a unique point B of P such that $\vec u=\overrightarrow{AB}$

Please feel free to correct anything in this post ! 
Thanks for reading this quite long question,

T.D

Comment: I don’t see how you can have $(A,A)\sim(B,B)$ when $A\ne B$. If these line segments include their endpoints, then the midpoint of $[A;A]$ is $A$ and the midpoint of $[B;B]$ is $B\ne A$. If they don’t, then neither segment has a midpoint and so they don’t share a midpoint, which your definition of $\sim$ requires. This can be fixed, but requires a more careful definition of this relation.

Comment: @amd I considered that ABBA was a parallellogram, maybe I should mention this.

Comment: I believe your definition of "equipollent" should have $\ (A,B) \sim (C,D)\ $ if the line segments $\ [A;D]\ $ and $\ [C;B]\ $ (*not* $\ [A;B]\ $ and $\ [C;D]\ $) share the same midpoint.

Comment: yep correcting it at once !

Comment: So, what is the question?

Comment: It was Proof checking/share knowledge

Comment: "share knowledge" is not a question. If it's proof-checking you want, please make that clearer.

Comment: This is what I want I'll make it clearer

Comment: "Two non-null bipoints are equipollents iff they are collinear": I think you mean "iff they are parallel".

Comment: I defined collinear bipoints as being parallel to one another