# Proving a property of vector addition

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces, vectors

Following up on [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3350499/516412) 
of mine, I have constructed   an addition of two vectors,. I have defined the product of a vector by a scalar and proved all usual properties of these operations, and colinearity except for the following

I have yet to prove

$\forall a \in \mathbb{R} \forall \vec{u}, \vec{v}, a(\vec{u}+\vec{v}) =a\vec{u}+a  \vec{v} $

I thought about using the intercept theorem but I have yet to find an outline for the proof

Any help would be much appreciated

T. D

Comment: Once you have your theorem that bipoints are in the same equivalence class if they are parallel and have the same orientation and length, it follows that the equivalence class of a bipoint is the usual geometric vector between the two points, so why can't you just conclude that your bipoint classes inherit all the properties of the usual geometric vector? But if you would rather not build on existing theory, perhaps an example of one of your other proofs would give a flavor of what you're looking for.

Comment: ill do this thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will show you the proof of this property in elementary (planar) geometry using my own definitions.

The call any ordered pair of points $(a,b)$ a *vector* and denote it by $\overrightarrow{ab}$. Next we introduce a two-argument relation $\sim$ between vectors: We say that $\overrightarrow{ab}\sim\overrightarrow{cd}$ whenever

1. $a=b$ and $c=d$
2. $a\neq b,c\neq d, ab\equiv cd$ and

   1. $L(ab)=L(cd)$ and $H(ab),H(cd)$ have the same direction
   2. $L(ab)\cap L(cd)=\emptyset$ and $H(ab),H(cd)$ lie on the same side of $L(ac)$

where $L(pq)$ is a line going through $p,q$ and $H(pq)$ is a halfline with origin $p$ going through $q$.

One can prove that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation. Equivalence classes are called *free vectors*. Next we say that a (free) vector $\overrightarrow{w}$ is a *sum* of vectors $\overrightarrow{v}$ and $\overrightarrow{u}$ whenever there exist points $p,q,r$ such that $\overrightarrow{pq}\in\overrightarrow{v}, \overrightarrow{qr}\in\overrightarrow{u},\overrightarrow{pr}\in\overrightarrow{w}$.

And given a real number $a$ we say that a (free) vector $\overrightarrow{u}$ is a *product* of $a$ and a vector $\overrightarrow{v}$ whenever

1. ($a=0$ or $\overrightarrow{v}=\overrightarrow{0}$) and $u=\overrightarrow{0}$
2. $a>0, \overrightarrow{v}\neq\overrightarrow{0}$ and there exist points $o\neq p,q$ such that $\overrightarrow{op}\in \overrightarrow{v},\overrightarrow{oq}\in \overrightarrow{u}$, $|oq|=a\cdot |op|$ and $p,q$ lie on the same halfline with origin $o$.
3. $a<0, \overrightarrow{v}\neq\overrightarrow{0}$ and there exist points $o\neq p,q$ such that $\overrightarrow{op}\in \overrightarrow{v},\overrightarrow{oq}\in \overrightarrow{u}$, $|oq|=-a\cdot |op|$ and $p,q$ lie on complementary halflines with origin $o$.

One can prove that for any two vectors $\overrightarrow{v}$ and $\overrightarrow{u}$ there exists exactly one vector $\overrightarrow{w}$ which is the sum. Therefore we can denote the sum by $\overrightarrow{v}+\overrightarrow{u}$.

Similarly for any real number $a$ and vector $\overrightarrow{v}$ there exists exactly one vector which is the product. Therefore we can denote it by $a\cdot\overrightarrow{v}$.

Now we can take on the theorem you want to prove.

**Lemma.** For any point $o$ and a free vector $\overrightarrow{v}$ there exists exactly one point $p$ such that $\overrightarrow{op}\in\overrightarrow{v}$.

I will assume that all other axioms of vector space hold for $+$ and $\cdot$ since they can be proved independently.

**Proof of the theorem.** Fix free vectors $\overrightarrow{v},\overrightarrow{u}$ and a real number $a$. The theorem is clearly true if $a=0$ or $\overrightarrow{v}=\overrightarrow{0}$ or $\overrightarrow{u}=\overrightarrow{0}$. Assume otherwise.
Pick a point $o$ and using the lemma find points $p,q$ such that $\overrightarrow{op}\in-\overrightarrow{v}=(-1)\cdot \overrightarrow{v},\overrightarrow{oq}\in\overrightarrow{u}$. If $o,p,q$ are collinear, it is easy to verify that $\overrightarrow{v}=b\cdot\overrightarrow{u}$ for some real number $b$ (even nonzero). Therefore $$a\cdot(\overrightarrow{v}+\overrightarrow{u})=a\cdot(b\cdot\overrightarrow{u}+\overrightarrow{u})=a\cdot(b\cdot\overrightarrow{u}+1\cdot\overrightarrow{u})=a\cdot((b+1)\cdot\overrightarrow{u})=(a(b+1))\cdot\overrightarrow{u}=(ab+a)\cdot\overrightarrow{u}=(ab)\cdot\overrightarrow{u}+a\cdot\overrightarrow{u}=a\cdot(b\cdot\overrightarrow{u})+a\cdot\overrightarrow{u}=a\cdot\overrightarrow{v}+a\cdot\overrightarrow{u} $$

Assume $o,p,q$ aren't collinear. The theorem is also trivial for $a= 1$. Asuume otherwise.

1. First case: $a>0$ find points $p',q'$ on halflines $H(op),H(oq)$ respectively such that $|op'|=a|op|,|oq'|=a|oq|$. Then $p\neq p',q\neq q'$ (because $a\neq 1$). Clearly $\overrightarrow{op'}\in a\cdot(-\overrightarrow{v})=-a\cdot\overrightarrow{v},\overrightarrow{oq'}\in a\cdot\overrightarrow{u}$ and $$[\overrightarrow{pq}]= [\overrightarrow{po}]+[\overrightarrow{oq}]=\overrightarrow{v}+\overrightarrow{u},[\overrightarrow{p'q'}]= [\overrightarrow{p'o}]+[\overrightarrow{oq'}]= a\cdot\overrightarrow{v}+a\cdot\overrightarrow{u}$$.

By the converse of intercept theorem we know that $pq\parallel p'q'$ and $|p'q'|=a|pq|$. Also halflines $H(pq), H(p'q')$ lie on the same side of $L(pp')$. On halfline $H(p'q')$ find point $q''$ such that $pq\equiv p'q''$. Clearly $\overrightarrow{pq}\sim\overrightarrow{p'q''}$ and $$a\cdot\overrightarrow{v}+a\cdot\overrightarrow{u}=[\overrightarrow{p'q'}]=a\cdot[\overrightarrow{p'q''}]=a\cdot[\overrightarrow{pq}]=a (\overrightarrow{v}+\overrightarrow{u})$$

2. Second case: $a<0$. We apply the first case for $-a>0$ and we obtain
   $$(-a)\overrightarrow{v}+(-a)\overrightarrow{u}=(-a)(\overrightarrow{v}+\overrightarrow{u})$$
   After some computation we get what we want (all rules we apply don't require the fact we are proving).

Comment: Thanks for the time. What do you mean by $ad\equiv bc $ ?

Comment: $ad\equiv bc$ means that segment $ad$ is congruent to segment $bc$. It is usually a primitive notion (e.g. in Hilbert's or Tarski's axioms). It is also equivalent to $|ad|=|bc|$ where $|\cdot|$ is a segment measure or $\rho(a,d)=\rho(b,c)$ where $\rho$ is a metric.

Answer (score 0):

It's the penultimate axiom in the table [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Definition), so don't try proving it from the other axioms.

Comment: My construction does not rely on these axioms and permit the use of all properties of standard geometry

Comment: @T.D. I realise you probably explain your definition of "vectors" in the other question, but I suggest you edit the information into this one to make it self-contained. There's an easy proof if you know your vector space has a basis, but I'll see what info you add in.